# How can I get wikimedia's jquery.i18n plugin to work with external files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, wikimedia

I can't get wikimedia's jquery.i18n plugin to work with external files.

This :

```
// Localisation
$.i18n.debug = true;
$.i18n().load( {
    'fr' : {
        'message-hello' : 'bonjour!'
},
'en': '/assets/i18n/en.json'
} );
$.i18n().locale = 'fr';
console.log($.i18n('message-hello'));
```

is working perfectly. Console says:

```
Loading messages from: /assets/i18n/en.json jquery.i18n.js:269
bonjour!
```

but this :

```
// Localisation
$.i18n.debug = true;
$.i18n().load( {
    'fr' : {
        'message-hello' : 'bonjour!'
},
'en': '/assets/i18n/en.json'
} );
$.i18n().locale = 'en';
console.log($.i18n('message-hello'));
```

is not. Console says:

```
Loading messages from: /assets/i18n/en.json jquery.i18n.js:269
message-hello
```

What am I missing ?

Here is my `/assets/i18n/en.json` file :

```
{
    "@metadata": {
        "authors": [
            "Alice",
            "David",
            "Santhosh"
        ],
        "last-updated": "2012-09-21",
        "locale": "en",
        "message-documentation": "qqq",
        "AnotherMetadata": "AnotherMedatadataValue"
    },
    "appname-title": "Example Application",
    "appname-sub-title": "An example application with jquery.i18n",
    "appname-header-introduction": "Introduction",
    "appname-about": "About this application",
    "appname-footer": "Footer text",
    "message-hello": "hello!"
}
```

EDIT : If i do `$.i18n('message-hello')` from the console, it works. Could this be because the json file is not yet loaded when I call `$.i18n('message-hello')` from my script ? And if so, how can I tell the script to wait until it is ?

Comment: what happens if you do `$.i18n.prop('message-hello')`?

Comment: I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

OK so it seems that when I call `console.log($.i18n('message-hello'));`, the JSON file has not been loaded yet. The workaround I've found is to use the `done()` method and wrap all my other code inside.

```
$.i18n.debug = true;
$.i18n().locale = 'en';
$.i18n().load( {
    'fr' : {
        'message-hello' : 'bonjour!'
    },
    'en': '/assets/i18n/en.json'
}).done( function() {

    // All my other JS code

});
```

If someone has a better solution, I'll take it.

Comment: If load() is returning a promise, that likely *is* the solution.